# Adding EF object as a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Ok, I've been pulling my hair out over this for a few days now.

How do I instruct entity framework to insert an object as a foreign key to an existing object, rather than as an entirely new object? I have tried all sorts of things. I keep getting the error "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

I'm just trying to add a country to an address. The countries are all listed in a separate database table. The country comes from a dropdown list posted from an MVC view so I only have the ID. This means the only way I can get the object is to query EF which results in a duplicate object.

Hope someone can help. Aaarg!

M

=== More info ===

While the above points out quite correctly to just set the countryID, this only works for create scenarios. It doesn't work for edit.

I have this in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(SiteViewModel siteViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Site site = _unitOfWork.SiteRepository.GetById(siteViewModel.SiteID);
            _unitOfWork.Detach(site);
            site = Mapper.Map<SiteViewModel, Site>(siteViewModel);
            site.CountryId = siteViewModel.CountryId;
            ...
        }
    }
```

I am still now getting the multiple objects with the same key error. How do I detach the country so I can re-add it again (!) without removing it from the database??

Please help!

M

Comment: could you please post the `Country` and `Address` entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var id = 2; // id of item 

using (var context = new Context())
      {
            var item = context.YourTable.Single(m => m.Id== id);

            item.ForeinKey = someNewForeinKey;

            context.SubmitChanges();
      }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Please see for more info above.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest way to attach the country to the address is to use a **Stub** to represent the country which you then attach to the address. **This avoids a round trip to the database in this scenario where you just want to attach the existing country without editing it.**

E.g.

```
// Create stub country using posted country id
var country = new Country { Id = postedId };

// Attach (NOT ADD) to context as an existing entity
// (Using Add would lead to an EntityState of Added and a violation of the
// PK unique constraint as per the question)
context.Countries.Attach(country)

// This assumes the address is attached to the context
// I.e. either its been Added to the Address DbSet
// or returned from a query on the Address DbSet
address.Country = country
context.SaveChanges();
```

As noted by Iain Galloway in the comments, if your Address-->Country relationship also has a foreign key id property, you could also achieve the same as follows:

```
address.CountryId = postedId;
```

Entity Framework will perform a relationship fixup when `DetectChanges` is called via the `SaveChanges` method and ensure that all the navigation properties are set correctly.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you can also simply set `address.CountryId` if it exists in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ForeignKey** attribute. That way you can assign an id instead of having the whole object. Just include an int property to your class and decorate the navigation property with the attribute saying that the int property represents a foreign key.